# How to find number of available tabs in a page, in Android?

Tags: android, tabs

I want to fix ten tabs. However, it will only set only four per page. How can I set the number of tabs? I get the total number of tabs by using

```
this.getTabHost().getTabWidget().getTabCount()
```

but I want to know how to set number of visible tabs per page. Could you give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set any number. What you need to do is, just add the tabs in the tab widget. It will automatically take the total number of tabs.

Comment: I want this type.! Only 4tabs are visible then on first left click show 5 to 8 and second left click show 7 to 10. How to make this?